# Predict a number with a given image (0 to 1)

Tags: mongodb, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am a total beginner to ML and Neural networks. I am currently working on a project where I have a lot of pictures stored in a MongoDB database. Each one of those pictures has a number from 0 to 1. For example "picture 1" 0.71.

I want to train my model given the database. The main goal for the project is that after the model is finished and trained, given an image the model will be able to return(predict) a number from 0 to 1. After doing some research and asking a few people I figured out some libraries that would be useful for the project are: Tenserflow and Keras. Some people told me that it is impossible, but I'm not sure therefore I came to ask here.

So my questions are: Is it possible? If so, how can I implement it? Are there any specific tools you recommend? If you specify a way that I should use for my project do I need to export my MongoDB database in a certain form? Since I am a beginner maybe there are some tutorials that you think that can help?

I'm sorry if this question is a bit too general, if there are any misunderstandings please comment and I will try to answer.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is totally feasible, this kind of project is called **regression**, since you are using images data the best type of models are called **convolutional neural network (CNN)**, you'll need some understanding if you want to build your own model. I've done a project where I had to predict a number of bacterial colonies using an image, much like your problem except that I had no boundaries on the predicted values.

What is a CNN ? Here is a [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5)

Basically a CNN will understand the features in the images and will use those features to predict a value.

You won't need to create your own model, most people just use well-designed one in the scientific litterature.

Go for keras, it's the easiest framework out there and work like a charm. Here is how to implement **VGG16** (an architecture that is probably the best for your problem) : [link](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3)

You should follow [this tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) to get going on developing with keras.

Last hint: don't use the same last layer as the one on the VGG16 implementation, use a Dense Layer with one neuron and with a **sigmoid/linear/leaky relu** activation.

ie:

```py
#model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

This means : predict `1` number (sigmoid will bound it between 0 and 1, but maybe lrelu or linear is better)

Also, I guess you could use MongoDB to read the images as arrays, but I would just put the images on a folder.

Edit : When compiling the model, use a `mean squared error` as in

```py
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I will start reading about CNNs and try and follow the tutorial you gave me. I have one more question. You said I shoulden't create a new model for myself and I should use an existing model. I am not entirely sure what that model means and how I can change it according to what I need. Or maybe I should leave it as is, and just train it with my dataset? Also, just one more small thing. I see that after training the CNN they test it. However, if it is already trained can I also just run one image on it and get the prediction?

Comment: A model is an architecture, a stacking of layers, in the case of VGG16 you start with convolution then dense, that's a model. You should start by letting the model like that, look how it performs. If your images are `too small` like 50x50, an architecture as deep as VGG16 should be reduced (removing some convolutions for example, less filters...). In the case of my project on bacterial colonies I only used 3 blocks of convs. WHen it will be trained on your data, you won't have to retrain it, you could use the model on just one image

Comment: Usually the more data you have, the bigger your network can be, but sometimes for small images even if you have a lot of data, having a network that is too deep is not the best. What I usually do to make my mind is looking at arxiv.com and see architecture used in the same kind of project that I have. Also for the inference after the training, you will need to save the weights of your model after the training and then to load them whenever you want to predict on images

Comment: Hi man, I was going through some regression tutorials and I came across [this one](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/28/keras-regression-and-cnns/) . I know right now it is working with 4 images and resizing them into one image but I think I can change the model a little bit and get it to work with just basic images and make predictions. What do you think?

Comment: That's a good start, once you have all your code that works the way you like to (training + validation) maybe you can look at `tensorboard` if you want to plot curves and all. Next step would be to design a better model because the one on the tutorial is very simple

Comment: Hi again, so I finished the course that I sent you here before. I have some basic understanding now. I don't fully understand what epochs mean. Also, using this mode with the tutorial I got that I am basically 57% off which is bad. I can try using this model for my use and see the results. In my case I would also have a lot more data so I think that would help. I still don't fully understand how I can take one's model and implement it for my own use. Does it already come ready for use and I just give it my data (images/csv), is there something I need to change. Which model should I pick?

Comment: An epoch is a use of all your data, while batch is a small part of your data. For example if you had 1000 images divided in 100 batches of 10, then your epochs will last 1000images (so 100 batches). Model is just a design, nothing else, you use conv layer to "understand" the images, dense layer to classify. Start with the same model, the difference will be made on the input and output shape

Comment: And look the last part of my post, I would advise to use VGG16 architecture which is somewhat good for what you want to do. It's a consecutive sequence of conv layers that deeply recognize the features of your images and the last layer should be change to output only one value. As I said you'll need to adapt the input shape so that it fits your data.

Comment: Hi please check my follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698373/machine-learning-regression-model-predicts-same-value-for-every-image

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/) you have the "hello world program" in terms of neural networks and digits classification. You can start studying it because I think you will end up with a similar architecture for your NN. What you should focus on is the output of your model, because in this example they are performing classification on 10 classes (digits from 0 to 9) but you are trying to read a real number. You could try to use a single neurone with sigmoid or linear [activation](https://keras.io/activations/) at the end of your model.

Comment: Hi please check out my follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698373/machine-learning-regression-model-predicts-same-value-for-every-image