# Machine learning regression model predicts same value for every image

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression

I am currently working on a project involving training a regression model, saving it and then loading it to make further predictions using that model. However I'm having a problem. Each time that I model.predict on images it gives out the same predictions. I am not entirely sure what the problem is, maybe it's in the training stage or i'm just doing something wrong.
I was following [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/28/keras-regression-and-cnns/)

All of the files are in this [github repo](https://github.com/tomercahal/statispic_ML)

Here are some bits from the code:
(This part is training the model and saving it)

```
model = create_cnn(400, 400, 3, regress=True)
opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=70, batch_size=8)
model.save("D:/statispic2/final-statispic_model.hdf5")
```

The next code part is from loading the model and making predictions.

```
model = load_model("D:/statispic2/statispic_model.hdf5")  # Loading the model
prediction = model.predict(images_ready_for_prediction) #images ready for prediction include a numpy array 
#that is loaded with the images just like I loaded them for the training stage.
print(prediction_list)
```

After trying it out this is the output prediction from the model:

```
[[0.05169942]  # I gave it 5 images as parameters 
[0.05169942]
[0.05169942]
[0.05169942]
[0.05169942]]
```

If anything is unclear, or you would like to see some more code, please let me know.

Comment: I have normalized the images beforehand by dividing all the pixels by 255.0

Comment: @Mike no, this is a regression model.

Comment: It is mentioned in the title that the model is a regression model.

Comment: What are you looking to predict? (Nevermind Housing Prices with images)

Comment: I don't think it would be possible at this moment to give you an answer, consider putting all the code. If you really want to get to the bottom of it I suggest you use a dataset that can be fetched automatically, then you're guaranteed 100% to get an answer.

Comment: @Mike I am trying to predict values for new imges. At the training stage each image had a number for it which I called the success ratio. After training the model i wanted to predict new success ratios for new images.

Comment: Hi @NicolasGervais ! I thought about giving you guys the code files so you guys can have a better understanding of what I am trying to do, but then the question would get to messy and probably get many downvotes. How would you recommend that I do this? So you guys could help me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @NicolasGervais added them now. lmk if you have any thoughts on how I can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I tried it and encountered a bunch of unrelated problems. The tutorial is using deprecated versions. I always had huge problems with Adrian Rosebrock's tutorials, I would seriously not recommend

Comment: @NicolasGervais gotcha, however the tutorial is from a year ago so I think the problem is not there. Also, I have tried running the original tutorial using the house images provided and it worked. Is there anything in there that you think is outdated and that I should change? I couldn't find another tutorial that covered something like this. I think that in the training process/the model something  is causing it to be somewhat of a 1 output function. Do you have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong. The code is available in the github repo mentions above.

Answer (score 6):

People saying regression and CNN are two completely different things clearly have missed some basic learnings in their ML course. Yes they are completely different! But should not be compared ;)

CNN is a type of deep neural network usually which became quite famous for its use on images. Therefore it is a framework to solve problem, and can solve both regression AND classification problems.

Regression refers to the type of output you are predicting. So comparing the two directly is quite stupid to be honest.

I cant comment on the specific people misleading you in this section, since I need a specific number of points to do so.

However, back to the problem. Do you encounter this problem before or after saving it? If you encounter it before, I would try scaling your output values to an easier distribution. If it happens after you save, I would look into versions of your framework and the documentation of how they save it.

It could also just be that there is no information in the pictures.

Answer (score 2):

No, no, no!  Regression is completely different from CNN.  Do a little research and the differences will quickly become apparent.  In the meantime, I'll share two code samples with you right here.

Regression:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline
import sklearn

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

# Now we will load the data into a pandas dataframe and then will print the first few rows of the data using the head() function.
bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
bos.head()

bos.columns = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
bos.head()

bos['MEDV'] = boston.target

bos.describe()

bos.isnull().sum()

sns.distplot(bos['MEDV'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
sns.pairplot(bos)
```

[image]

```
corr_mat = bos.corr().round(2)
sns.heatmap(data=corr_mat, annot=True)
```

[image]

```
sns.lmplot(x = 'RM', y = 'MEDV', data = bos)

X = bos[['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX','PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']]
y = bos['MEDV']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 10)

# Training the Model
# We will now train our model using the LinearRegression function from the sklearn library.

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Prediction
# We will now make prediction on the test data using the LinearRegression function and plot a scatterplot between the test data and the predicted value.

prediction = lm.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_test, prediction)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted':prediction})
df2 = df1.head(10)
df2
df2.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print('MAE', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, prediction))
print('MSE', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, prediction))
print('RMSE', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, prediction)))
print('R squared error', r2_score(y_test, prediction))
```

Result:

```
MAE 4.061419182954711
MSE 34.413968453138565
RMSE 5.866341999333023
R squared error 0.6709339839115628
```

CNN:

```
# keras imports for the dataset and building our neural network
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten
from keras.utils import np_utils

# to calculate accuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# loading the dataset
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# building the input vector from the 28x28 pixels
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

# normalizing the data to help with the training
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# one-hot encoding using keras' numpy-related utilities
n_classes = 10
print("Shape before one-hot encoding: ", y_train.shape)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, n_classes)
print("Shape after one-hot encoding: ", Y_train.shape)

# building a linear stack of layers with the sequential model
model = Sequential()
# convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(25, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(1,1)))
# flatten output of conv
model.add(Flatten())
# hidden layer
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
# output layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# compiling the sequential model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

# training the model for 10 epochs
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Result:

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 451us/step - loss: 0.2037 - accuracy: 0.9400 - val_loss: 0.0866 - val_accuracy: 0.9745
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 451us/step - loss: 0.0606 - accuracy: 0.9819 - val_loss: 0.0553 - val_accuracy: 0.9812
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 445us/step - loss: 0.0352 - accuracy: 0.9892 - val_loss: 0.0533 - val_accuracy: 0.9824
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 446us/step - loss: 0.0226 - accuracy: 0.9930 - val_loss: 0.0572 - val_accuracy: 0.9825
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 448us/step - loss: 0.0148 - accuracy: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0516 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 443us/step - loss: 0.0088 - accuracy: 0.9976 - val_loss: 0.0574 - val_accuracy: 0.9824
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 26s 442us/step - loss: 0.0089 - accuracy: 0.9973 - val_loss: 0.0526 - val_accuracy: 0.9847
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 26s 440us/step - loss: 0.0047 - accuracy: 0.9988 - val_loss: 0.0593 - val_accuracy: 0.9838
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 28s 469us/step - loss: 0.0056 - accuracy: 0.9986 - val_loss: 0.0559 - val_accuracy: 0.9836
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 27s 449us/step - loss: 0.0059 - accuracy: 0.9981 - val_loss: 0.0663 - val_accuracy: 0.9820
```

Answer (score 0):

CNN is deep learning.  You use regression models  for calculating a number, like the price of a car.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue after `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load` my model. The problem I was missing is that I was not normalizing features (vector X) before predicting using the model. I hope the will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the optimizer from Adam() to RMSprop() with a learning rate of >0.001 worked for me.